# Server-side node.js templating and merging for text files

Tags: node.js, templates, angularjs

I am trying to see if there is a library that will allow me to do merging of a JSON object with a template (txt file) on the server side. Ideally, I would like it to be able to handle some conditional statements (e.g. if, greater than, equals etc.) and looping (e.g. for).

I know there are binding libraries (e.g. angularjs), and one option might be to hack it to extract the code required to do this. Alternatively, I could create my own solution, but would rather not re-invent the wheel.

I am new to Nodejs, so I'm thinking this seems like a problem that might have been solved already.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) or [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)?

Comment: Jade was no good, because it is a logic-less templating engine. EJS was an option, but ended up going with doT.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good.

Ended up going with [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/). Great library for what I'm doing.